# Why is IsInRole throwing an error?

Tags: security, model-view-controller, iis

I have an MVC application that is using a mix of windows and forms.  The database is on a hosted server and I'm using my local IIS (5.1).

Everything works fine until I try using IsInRole("role") - I get:

**The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed.**

I suspect this may be OK when the application is deployed as it will be all on an intranet but I need to check roles in development.

The users and roles do exist in my aspnet tables in the Db and as I say it works if I use my local DB for development too.

Any ideas appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Davy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I have set a loca version of the membership table to manage roles.  This is not ideal but allows me to fake the roles for development.

It would be great if these could be on the shared DB server too.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a domain issue. See the [kb 162797](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/162797) article. Probably your passwords are mismatched or some configuration is corrupted.
Try dis joining and joining the domain again. That should fix it.